# Telecommunications Symbols

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw some telecommunications objects to put in a more complex figure using `PGF/TikZ`. I know there must be a better way to do it and even write their names `UE`, `BS`, etc. . Any help is appreciated

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\UEA}{%
\begin{pgfpicture}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
\pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{2cm}{2cm}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{2cm}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{3cm}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{2cm}{3cm}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0cm}{3cm}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{4cm}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{pgfpicture}
}

\newcommand{\UEB}{%
\begin{pgfpicture}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{5cm}{0cm}}
\pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpoint{5cm}{0cm}}{\pgfpoint{7cm}{2cm}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{6cm}{2cm}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{6cm}{3cm}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{7cm}{4cm}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{5cm}{4cm}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{6cm}{3cm}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{pgfpicture}
}

\newcommand{\BSA}{%
\begin{pgfpicture}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{10cm}{0cm}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{12cm}{0cm}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{11cm}{3cm}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{11cm}{3cm}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{11cm}{4cm}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{12cm}{4cm}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{10cm}{4cm}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{11cm}{5cm}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{pgfpicture}
}

\newcommand{\BSB}{%
\begin{pgfpicture}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{10cm}{0cm}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{12cm}{0cm}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{11cm}{3cm}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{11cm}{3cm}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{11cm}{4cm}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{12cm}{4cm}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{10cm}{4cm}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{12cm}{4cm}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{12cm}{5cm}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{11.5cm}{5cm}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{12.5cm}{5cm}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{12cm}{5.5cm}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{10cm}{4cm}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{10cm}{5cm}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{9.5cm}{5cm}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{10.5cm}{5cm}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{10cm}{5.5cm}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{pgfpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\UEA \quad \UEB \quad \BSA \quad \BSB
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for providing a MWE, but why are you not just using `tikzpicture` instead? I don't have much experience with these low level commands, so am sure there is a good reason for using them when building libraries, but if this is for your own usage, using `tikzpicture` is simpler -- well at least for me.

Comment: Could you provide a link to a document or webpage where those symbols are used?

Comment: Well... I don't have. Latter I did some symbols. I will put the code below.

Answer (score 16):

Some symbols below, in different forms.[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{ellipsis}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings,shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{naming/.style={align=center,font=\small}}
\tikzset{antenna/.style={insert path={-- coordinate (ant#1) ++(0,0.25) -- +(135:0.25) + (0,0) -- +(45:0.25)}}}
\tikzset{station/.style={naming,draw,shape=dart,shape border rotate=90, minimum width=10mm, minimum height=10mm,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=3pt}}
%\tikzset{mobile/.style={naming,draw,shape=rectangle,minimum width=15mm,minimum height=7.5mm, outer sep=0pt,inner sep=3pt}}
\tikzset{mobile/.style={naming,draw,shape=rectangle,minimum width=12mm,minimum height=6mm, outer sep=0pt,inner sep=3pt}}
\tikzset{radiation/.style={{decorate,decoration={expanding waves,angle=90,segment length=4pt}}}}

\newcommand{\MUE}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={rectangle,minimum width=0pt}]
\node [mobile,label={[inner ysep=+.3333em]\dots}] (box) {#1};

%\node [mobile] (box) {#1};
%\node at ($(ant1)!0.5!(ant2)$) {\dots};

\draw ([xshift=.25cm] box.south west) circle (4pt)
      ([xshift=-.25cm]box.south east) circle (4pt);

\fill ([xshift=.25cm] box.south west) circle (1pt)
      ([xshift=-.25cm]box.south east) circle (1pt);

\draw ([xshift=.25cm] box.north west) [antenna=1];
\draw ([xshift=-.25cm]box.north east) [antenna=2];
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\UE}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={rectangle,minimum width=0pt}]
\node[mobile] (box) {#1};

\draw ([xshift=.25cm] box.south west) circle (4pt)
      ([xshift=-.25cm]box.south east) circle (4pt);

\fill ([xshift=.25cm] box.south west) circle (1pt)
      ([xshift=-.25cm]box.south east) circle (1pt);

\draw (box.north) [antenna=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\MBS}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[station] (base) {#1};

%\draw[line join=bevel] (base.110) -- (base.70) -- (base.north west) -- (base.north east) -- cycle;
\draw[line join=bevel] (base.100) -- (base.80) -- (base.110) -- (base.70) -- (base.north west) -- (base.north east);
\draw[line join=bevel] (base.100) -- (base.70) (base.110) -- (base.north east);

% original yshift=.8pt
%\draw[line cap=rect] ([xshift=.5cm,yshift=.3pt] base.north) [antenna=1];
%\draw[line cap=rect] ([yshift=.3pt]ant1 |- base.north) -- node[above,shape=rectangle,inner ysep=+.3333em]{\dots} ([xshift=-.5cm,yshift=.3pt]base.north) [antenna=2];
\draw[line cap=rect] ([xshift=-.1768cm,yshift=.6pt]base.north -| base.right tail) [antenna=1];
\draw[line cap=rect] ([yshift=.6pt]ant1 |- base.north) -- node[above,shape=rectangle,inner ysep=+.3333em]{\dots} ([xshift=.1768cm,yshift=.6pt]base.north -| base.left tail) [antenna=2];

%\draw[line cap=rect] ([yshift=.3pt]ant1 |- base.north) -- ([xshift=-.5cm,yshift=.3pt]base.north) [antenna=2];
%\node at ($(ant1)!0.5!(ant2)$) {\dots};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\BS}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[station] (base) {#1};

%\draw[line join=bevel] (base.110) -- (base.70) -- (base.north west) -- (base.north east) -- cycle;
\draw[line join=bevel] (base.100) -- (base.80) -- (base.110) -- (base.70) -- (base.north west) -- (base.north east);
\draw[line join=bevel] (base.100) -- (base.70) (base.110) -- (base.north east);

% original yshift=.8pt
\draw[line cap=rect] ([yshift=0pt]base.north) [antenna=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[every path/.append style={thick}]

\matrix[column sep=0.5cm,row sep=0.5cm]
{
    \node{\BS{1}}; & \node{\UE{2}}; & \node{\MBS{3}}; & \node{\MUE{4}};\\
    \node[draw,fill=yellow!30,label=below:SISO] {\BS{1}}; &
    \node[draw,shape=circle,fill=red!30,label={left:\rotatebox{90}{SISO}}] {\UE{2}}; &
    \node[draw,fill=blue!30,label=above:MIMO] {\MBS{3}}; &
    \node[blue,shape=circle,fill=green!30,inner sep=0pt,label={right:\rotatebox{-90}{MIMO}}] {\MUE{4}};\\
    \node[every path/.append style={thick},inner sep=0pt](A){\BS{\textbf{1}}}; & \node(B){\UE{2}}; & \node(C){\MBS{3}}; & \node[magenta,inner sep=0pt](D){\MUE{\textcolor{black}{4}}};\\
};

\draw[thick,radiation,decoration={angle=45}] ([xshift=.1768cm]A.north) -- +(45:0.5);
\draw[thick,radiation,decoration={angle=45}] ([xshift=-.1768cm]A.north) -- +(135:0.5);
\draw[radiation] (B.north) -- +(90:0.5);
\draw[radiation] (C.north) -- +(90:0.5);
\draw[red,radiation,decoration={angle=45}] ([xshift=.25cm,yshift=3pt]D.north west) -- +(90:0.5);
\draw[green,radiation,decoration={angle=45}] ([xshift=-.25cm,yshift=3pt]D.north east) -- +(90:0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```